# Bluetooth tracker app killed from Android OS

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm currently developing an app in Cordova to manage a bluetooth tracker. The app needs to monitor connection/disconnection of known trackers, register GPS coordinates when a tracker disconnect, and make the phone ring if a connected tracker's button is pressed.

But I have a problem when the app is put in background: the app stops running in Android if I open other apps. I believe that the OS kills my app if it needs memory.

In iOS it is really simple to prevent the OS to stop the app when it goes to background, following [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) : I declare that the app connects with bluetooth accessories and use GPS locations, and it can continue to work in the background running everything needed.

For Android, I don't know how to reach this behaviour. Will [this plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) (Katzer background mode) prevent the OS from killing the app when it needs memory if it is in background? From what I read it seems so.
If no, what is your suggested way to achieve that behaviour?

Another thing is: if I use this plugin, will my app be compliant with Play Store?

Comment: I looked at what cordova does. I did not knew. I deleted my answer. But if you want to run something when your app is not active, use a service

Comment: Using a service would involve to rewrite all the code I want to be executed in background in Java from what I understood.
That would be a total mess since it would cause me to rewrite a big part of the app code, and I would lose the benefit of having developed an hybrid app in Cordova.
Is there a way to simply create a service, and let it run a javascript code?

Besides, I don't get what this plugin is usable for if it doesn't allow to avoid the app to be killed...can someone explain me?